# Simulate location change in emulator for Codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

Is there any way you can simulate a change in the lat,lng co-ordinates using the simulator for codename one ?
I know it gives me one static location each time.

I am trying to see if I can change this location using the simulator so that I can implement some sort of tracking using google maps.

Or do I have to get out on the streets to test this ?
BR,
Sanket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer !

The simulator automatically does this. Implement a LocationListener() and check in locationUpdated().